# Visa annulment or revocation - spending more days in another Schengen state than the issuing state

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, tourist-visas, visa-shopping

Good day everyone,

My wife and I applied and got a tourist Schengen visa (type C) to Hungary. We entered and exited from Hungary respecting time frames.

When we came back, we were requested to provide our passports to the consulate for revocation or annulment of the visa. (It was in Arabic on the document)

When we inquired for the reason, the explanation was that we spent more days in another Schengen state than the days we spent in the issuing state.

What are the implications for this in terms of applying for future Schengen visas?

Note: we each have numerous Schengen type C visas on our passports, we never break the law or rules. And we have never had any issue at all.

#### Edit additional info:

1. We went for 21 days, we spent 4 nights in Hungary, 5 in Paris, 6 in Spain and a couple here and there in Belgium and Germany.
2. How did they find out? When receiving our passports with the visa, we were provided with a document we had to sign that required us to provide proof of accommodation, transportation and exit/entry to Schengen territory upon our return. Which we did of course.
3. The visa issued was type C (no exceptions for a specific member state). The time allowed 28 days. Single entry.
4. We stayed 21 days, entered and exited from the country providing the visa.
5. We did not break the law or time frame allowed for use or exceed the last date of exit.

Comment: Did you actually spend more time in other countries while on that visa? How did they even know? Once you enter the Schengen Area, it becomes very difficult for anyone to know in which exact country you are at any given time. I believe we must be missing a lot of relevant information here.

Comment: Why would someone want to revoke your visa after you have legally left already? I have never heard consulates do that. And why would a European consulate write to you in Arabic? Are you sure that the request is genuine?

Comment: A european consulate writing in the local language is not that unusual. The main question remains: did you indeed spend more time in a different cointry?

Comment: @HankyPanky Perhaps the visa is valid for a significant time into the future, and the consulate learned that in its last use, the visa holder violated the visa's terms by spending more time in one place than was allowed under the visa's terms. It's reasonable that the consulate might wish to revoke the visa (so it could not be used again) or annul it so the earlier travel might be flagged as contrary to law, or the traveler flagged as not to be trusted if if the traveler again applies for a visa.

Comment: Was the whole trip just tourism, or was there any specific reason to go to Hungary (a business meeting, visiting relatives...)? If there was indeed no specific reason to go to Hungary, applying for the visa from Hungary was incorrect (you should have applied from Spain as it was the place your stayed the longer), and can be seen as "visa-shopping". It still seems like an over-reaction on their part though. If you had stayed 2 days in Hungary and 20 in one single other country I could have understood, but here you're really just over the edge.

Comment: Also, I don't quite understand the point of revoking a single-entry visa which has already been used... Someone is overzealous...

Comment: @jcaron That is true, but I think the reason behind this is more about future applications. But it is definitely nitpicking.

Comment: You can merge your accounts: https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 2):

> We went for 21 days, we spent 4 nights in Hungary, 5 in Paris, **6 in Spain** and a couple here and there in Belgium and Germany.

You should have applied for the visa at the Spanish consulate, since the primary portion of you visit was in Spain (6 days).

Had you also stayed in Hungary (where you applid for the visa) for 6 days, then the country you entered first (Hungary) would have been the proper country to make the application.

Since this was not the case, you are now facing this problem.

---

> **Where and how to apply**
>   You must lodge the application for a Schengen visa at the Consulate of the country that you intend to visit, or – if you intend to visit more than one Schengen State, the Consulate of the country where you will **spend the longest period**.
>
> If you intend to visit several Schengen States and the stays will be of equal length, you must apply at the Consulate of the country whose external borders you will cross first when entering the Schengen area.

---

**Sources**:

- [European Commission - Where and how to apply](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/how_to_apply_en)